# Django, Celery, RabbitMQ - Tasks are not been executed

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have setup my Django env like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
....
    'djcelery',

)

BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('bulksms.tasks', 'premiumsms.tasks', 'reports.tasks')
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

In the Django admin I add the task I want to periodic tasks (I can see all the tasks there) to run every minute for testing purposes but the task never runs.

```
Running django then 
python manage.py celeryd -E --loglevel=DEBUG
python manage.py celerycam
```

In the admin site under Djcelery there is also no option for Tasks to ADD (not sure if it used to be there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run periodic tasks with Celery then you need to run the celerybeat process with either

```
python manage.py celery beat
```

or using another thread in the worker process

```
python manage.py celery worker -E --loglevel=DEBUG -B
```

See the docs on starting the scheduler http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler

Comment: Dammit! I knew it was something stupid that forgot! Thanks Mark